# press sequence of buttons by sliding the finger on them?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, button, slider

I have a 2 dimensional recyclerview that contains buttons.
when the user **clicks** on the button it changes the layout color to green and vice versa.

I'm trying to add a feature that allows the user to slide the finger on the buttons row, and make the buttons get pressed.
couldn't find documentation about it.
I don't want to use slider widget because I would like to keep the buttons formation.
any ideas?

[image]

thanks

This is my setOnClickListener for the button ( the button is a circular layout):

```
    holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,WorkoutInterface.class);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isPressed[0] ==false){//check if the button is already pressed
                isPressed[0] =true;
                actualReps+=1;// add rep count to the actual reps variable
                if(workout.pressedButtons==null){//save the number of presses in list
                    workout.pressedButtons="";
                }else {
                    workout.pressedButtons+=","+String.valueOf(verticalIndex) + String.valueOf(position);
                    buttonColorCheck(holder, position, verticalIndex);//if button is pressed in the past, keep it green
                }
            }else{
                holder.linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,166, 172, 175) );
                isPressed[0] =false;
                actualReps-=1;
                changeButtonStatus(String.valueOf(verticalIndex)+String.valueOf(position));
                
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: set touch listener on the button and check touch contains an area of the button bounds.

Comment: @EAS I tried to use setOnTouchListener, but it did not do anything different. how can i check if it contains the area of the button bounds?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create it manually

```
public Rect btn1Rect= new Rect((int) btn1.getX(), (int) btn1.getY(), (int) btn1.getX() + btn1.getWidth(), (int) btn1.getY() + btn1.getHeight()); //bound of button 1


View.OnTouchListener buttonTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        int x= (int) event.getRawX(),y= (int) event.getRawY();

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(btn1Rect.contains(x,y)){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: your touch contains btn1 bound");
                }
                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
};
```

make sure that set touch listener to your buttons and remove click listener from it.